# In node-supervisor, how do I watch everything in a directory for changes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor

I want to watch everything inside the "api" directory and all its subdirectories (recursively). How can I do that?

```
sudo supervisor -w app.js,api app.js
```

This doesn't seem to work. It only watches the "api" directory, not its subdirectories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be working and detect changes for me.

If I use this to load the file:

```
var module = require("./folder/test/variables.js")
```

And Have a main node file:

```
var module = require("./folder/test/variables.js")
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   response.end('The variable is '+ module.variable)
}).listen(7777);
```

Then, just using:

```
supervisor myApp.js
```

is going to detect changes in folder/test/variables, which is a subfolder.

Actually, supervisor says it is monitoring the current folder:

```
DEBUG: Running node-supervisor with
DEBUG:   program 'myApp.js'
DEBUG:   --watch '.'
DEBUG:   --extensions 'node|js'
DEBUG:   --exec 'node'
```

It is also reloading the files in folder/test if I use:

```
supervisor -w folder myApp.js
```

So, I guess you may have a different version of supervisor ? I am using [0.2](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor/blob/master/package.json)

Answer (score 10):

I just watch all extensions I'm using:

```
supervisor -e 'js|ejs|less' app.js
```

Comment: for **all extensions**, you can use `supervisor -e '.' app.js`

Comment: don't know if this was available 4 years ago :)

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me to watch js and hbs files : supervisor -e 'js|hbs'  app.js